# Read data from a device through ethernet

Tags: c#, ethernet

I have a project to read data from a device(IND 560). The device has been connected through Ethernet. How can I do this with C# programming.

Can any one give me some idea or if you have any code that you developed please post here.

Comment: What protocol does the device use? Can you post what you have tried? You need to give us more information on the device itself.  There is no reason this cannot be written in C#.

Comment: http://samplecode.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/public/documents/webassets/sc_browse_results.hcst?PageNumber=18&StartRow=341&EndRow=360&SortField=xSC_Title_EN&SortOrder=Asc

Comment: The device is a scaled display. It weighs load of product and displays. And it connected to a laptop with ethernet. so I need to capture that weight data. The device is IND 560 (from Mettler Toledo)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [samples](http://us.mt.com/us/en/home/supportive_content/software_downloads/IND560EIPsmpl/_jcr_content/download/file/file.res/IND560%20EthernetIP%20sample%20code.zip) from the manufacturers website might be of use...?